# TweenJS animation not working

Tags: javascript, animation, createjs, tweenjs

I am working on a tool to perform sequence of animations by updating an object array. This array would have all the parameters  to customize animation as per varied requirements. This tool is being developed with JavaScript and makes use of createJS library and TweenJS to animate objects. Objects are created dynamically and positioned, then the tween is applied. Tween doesn't seem to work in my code.

I have the whole code below

```
    var AnimationFlow = (function () {
    'use strict';


    var AnimationFlow = function (canvasID) {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
        this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
        this.timeline = new createjs.Timeline();
        this.tween = [];

        this.preload;

        this.animData;
        this.manifest = [];
        this.animObject = [];
        this.stageObject = [];

        this.loadProgressLabel;
        this.loadingBarContainer;
        this.loadingBar;        
    };


    AnimationFlow.prototype.setData = function (data) {
        this.animData = data;
        this.manifest = [];

        this.renderProgressBar();

        for (var i = 0; i < this.animData.length; i++) {
            this.manifest.push({'src': this.animData[i].targeturl, 'id': this.animData[i].targetID});
        }
    };

    AnimationFlow.prototype.init = function () {

        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", this.tick.bind(this));
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
        createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;

        this.preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
        this.preload.addEventListener("complete", this.handleComplete.bind(this));
        this.preload.addEventListener("progress", this.handleProgress.bind(this));
        this.preload.loadManifest(this.manifest);
        this.stage.update();
    };

    AnimationFlow.prototype.handleProgress = function () {
        this.loadingBar.scaleX = this.preload.progress * this.loadingBarWidth;

        this.progresPrecentage = Math.round(this.preload.progress * 100);
        this.loadProgressLabel.text = this.progresPrecentage + "% Loaded";

        this.stage.update();
    };

    AnimationFlow.prototype.handleComplete = function () {
        //Load images logic to be added

        for (var i = 0; i < this.manifest.length; i++) {
            this.animObject.push(this.preload.getResult(this.manifest[i].id));
        }

        this.loadProgressLabel.text = "Loading complete click to start";
        this.stage.update();
        this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick.bind(this));
    };

    AnimationFlow.prototype.handleClick = function () {
        this.start();

        this.stage.removeChild(this.loadProgressLabel, this.loadingBarContainer);
        this.canvas.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
    };

    AnimationFlow.prototype.start = function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.animObject.length; i++) {
            this.obj = new createjs.Bitmap(this.animObject[i]);
            this.obj.x = this.animData[i].initialXPos;
            this.obj.y = this.animData[i].initialYPos;
            this.obj.visible = this.animData[i].initialVisibility;

            this.stage.addChild(this.obj);
            this.stageObject.push(this.obj);

            if(this.animData[i].isAnimatable){
                 var c = createjs.Tween.get(this.obj);
                  c.to({x:this.animData[i].params.xpos}, this.animData[i].duration);
                  c.call(this.tweenComplete);
                  this.timeline.addTween(c);
            }
        }
        this.stage.update();
    };

    AnimationFlow.prototype.tick = function () {
        console.log("heart beat on....");
        this.stage.update();
    };

    AnimationFlow.prototype.tweenComplete = function () {
        console.log("tweenComplete.......");        
    };

    AnimationFlow.prototype.renderProgressBar = function () {
        this.loadProgressLabel = new createjs.Text("", "18px Verdana", "black");
        this.loadProgressLabel.lineWidth = 200;
        this.loadProgressLabel.textAlign = "center";
        this.loadProgressLabel.x = this.canvas.width / 2;
        this.loadProgressLabel.y = 50;
        this.stage.addChild(this.loadProgressLabel);

        this.loadingBarContainer = new createjs.Container();

        this.loadingBarHeight = 20;
        this.loadingBarWidth = 300;
        this.LoadingBarColor = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0, 0, 0);

        this.loadingBar = new createjs.Shape();
        this.loadingBar.graphics.beginFill(this.LoadingBarColor).drawRect(0, 0, 1, this.loadingBarHeight).endFill();

        this.frame = new createjs.Shape();
        this.padding = 3;
        this.frame.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1).beginStroke(this.LoadingBarColor).drawRect(-this.padding / 2, -this.padding / 2, this.loadingBarWidth + this.padding, this.loadingBarHeight + this.padding);

        this.loadingBarContainer.addChild(this.loadingBar, this.frame);
        this.loadingBarContainer.x = Math.round(this.canvas.width / 2 - this.loadingBarWidth / 2);
        this.loadingBarContainer.y = 100;
        this.stage.addChild(this.loadingBarContainer);
    };

    return AnimationFlow;
})();



var data = [{targetID: 'background', targeturl: 'assets/images/heliGame/sky.png',isAnimatable:true, duration: 2000, params: {xpos: '600'}, isVisibleAfterAnimation: true, isVisibleAtStartAnimation: true, initialVisibility: true, initialXPos: '0', initialYPos: '0'},
    {targetID: 'mousePointer', targeturl: 'assets/images/heliGame/helicopter.png',isAnimatable:true, duration: 1000, params: {xpos: '500'}, isVisibleAfterAnimation: false, isVisibleAtStartAnimation: true, initialVisibility: true, initialXPos: '0', initialYPos: '0'}];

var buttons = ["playPauseBtn", "startFirstBtn", "reverseBtn"];


var animTool = new AnimationFlow('testCanvas');
animTool.setData(data);


animTool.init();
```

I have the code in JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesshaji/t4pxzsoo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues. Firstly, you need to define all of your positions as integers and not as strings (ie: take the quotes off of your position data in your data object). Secondly, you need to call: this.timeline.gotoAndPlay(0); to start the timeline execution. Otherwise the animations won't play. Here is a fixed version:

```js
var AnimationFlow = (function() {
  'use strict';


  var AnimationFlow = function(canvasID) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
    this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
    this.timeline = new createjs.Timeline();
    this.tween = [];

    this.preload;

    this.animData;
    this.manifest = [];
    this.animObject = [];
    this.stageObject = [];

    this.loadProgressLabel;
    this.loadingBarContainer;
    this.loadingBar;
  };


  AnimationFlow.prototype.setData = function(data) {
    this.animData = data;
    this.manifest = [];

    this.renderProgressBar();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.animData.length; i++) {
      this.manifest.push({
        'src': this.animData[i].targeturl,
        'id': this.animData[i].targetID
      });
    }
  };

  AnimationFlow.prototype.init = function() {

    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", this.tick.bind(this));
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
    createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;

    this.preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    this.preload.addEventListener("complete", this.handleComplete.bind(this));
    this.preload.addEventListener("progress", this.handleProgress.bind(this));
    this.preload.loadManifest(this.manifest);
    this.stage.update();
  };

  AnimationFlow.prototype.handleProgress = function() {
    this.loadingBar.scaleX = this.preload.progress * this.loadingBarWidth;

    this.progresPrecentage = Math.round(this.preload.progress * 100);
    this.loadProgressLabel.text = this.progresPrecentage + "% Loaded";

    this.stage.update();
  };

  AnimationFlow.prototype.handleComplete = function() {
    //Load images logic to be added

    for (var i = 0; i < this.manifest.length; i++) {
      this.animObject.push(this.preload.getResult(this.manifest[i].id));
    }

    this.loadProgressLabel.text = "Loading complete click to start";
    this.stage.update();
    this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick.bind(this));
  };

  AnimationFlow.prototype.handleClick = function() {
    this.start();

    this.stage.removeChild(this.loadProgressLabel, this.loadingBarContainer);
    this.canvas.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  };

  AnimationFlow.prototype.start = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.animObject.length; i++) {
      this.obj = new createjs.Bitmap(this.animObject[i]);
      this.obj.x = this.animData[i].initialXPos;
      this.obj.y = this.animData[i].initialYPos;
      this.obj.visible = this.animData[i].initialVisibility;

      this.stage.addChild(this.obj);
      this.stageObject.push(this.obj);

      if (this.animData[i].isAnimatable) {
        console.log("animatable:" + this.animData[i].params.xpos + " " + this.animData[i].duration);
        var c = createjs.Tween.get(this.obj);
        c.to({
          x: this.animData[i].params.xpos
        }, this.animData[i].duration);
        c.call(this.tweenComplete);
        this.timeline.addTween(c);
      }
    }
    this.timeline.gotoAndPlay(0);
    this.stage.update();
  };

  AnimationFlow.prototype.tick = function() {
    this.stage.update();
  };

  AnimationFlow.prototype.tweenComplete = function() {
    console.log("tweenComplete.......");
  };

  AnimationFlow.prototype.renderProgressBar = function() {
    this.loadProgressLabel = new createjs.Text("", "18px Verdana", "black");
    this.loadProgressLabel.lineWidth = 200;
    this.loadProgressLabel.textAlign = "center";
    this.loadProgressLabel.x = this.canvas.width / 2;
    this.loadProgressLabel.y = 50;
    this.stage.addChild(this.loadProgressLabel);

    this.loadingBarContainer = new createjs.Container();

    this.loadingBarHeight = 20;
    this.loadingBarWidth = 300;
    this.LoadingBarColor = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0, 0, 0);

    this.loadingBar = new createjs.Shape();
    this.loadingBar.graphics.beginFill(this.LoadingBarColor).drawRect(0, 0, 1, this.loadingBarHeight).endFill();

    this.frame = new createjs.Shape();
    this.padding = 3;
    this.frame.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1).beginStroke(this.LoadingBarColor).drawRect(-this.padding / 2, -this.padding / 2, this.loadingBarWidth + this.padding, this.loadingBarHeight + this.padding);

    this.loadingBarContainer.addChild(this.loadingBar, this.frame);
    this.loadingBarContainer.x = Math.round(this.canvas.width / 2 - this.loadingBarWidth / 2);
    this.loadingBarContainer.y = 100;
    this.stage.addChild(this.loadingBarContainer);
  };

  return AnimationFlow;
})();



var data = [{
  targetID: 'background',
  targeturl: 'https://s13.postimg.org/tyj4iop93/Sky_Pic.jpg',
  isAnimatable: true,
  duration: 2000,
  params: {
    xpos: -100
  },
  isVisibleAfterAnimation: true,
  isVisibleAtStartAnimation: true,
  initialVisibility: true,
  initialXPos: 0,
  initialYPos: 0
}, {
  targetID: 'mousePointer',
  targeturl: 'http://jamesshaji.com/angular/assets/images/heliGame/helicopter.png',
  isAnimatable: true,
  duration: 2000,
  params: {
    xpos: 100
  },
  isVisibleAfterAnimation: false,
  isVisibleAtStartAnimation: true,
  initialVisibility: true,
  initialXPos: 450,
  initialYPos: 50
}];

var buttons = ["playPauseBtn", "startFirstBtn", "reverseBtn"];


var animTool = new AnimationFlow('testCanvas');
animTool.setData(data);
animTool.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tweenjs/0.6.2/tweenjs.min.js"></script>

<div>Animation</div>

<canvas height="500" width="500" id="testCanvas">

</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help